# How to structure front-end Javascript for middle-sized websites

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a reasonable way to structure my Javascript code for regular websites that get more and more dependent on Javascript.

Large Javascript applications use - put your framework here, Angular, React, Backbone. Small websites suffice with just a list of `$().slider()`, `$().popup()` in a script style.

What I currently do is using the module pattern for different parts - slider, popup - and initialize these in my `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });` function. For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    HomeSlider.init();
    ImageGallery.init();

});
```

Libraries are loaded via Bower and automatically prepended by Gulp. Any other suggestions for that are welcome as well.

Once more libraries are added, more REST/AJAX-calls are made and pushState is used more often my Javascript starts to become a mess and keep track of what happens when/where.

I am looking for suggestions to structure this Javascript for 'regular and modern' websites without committing to a big framework and 'overengineering' my code. This might be in form of code examples, 'light' frameworks or any literature.

Thanks a lot for reading and maybe even answering my question!

Comment: weird. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Searches on structuring my JavaScript quickly leads to big frameworks, while a regular - let's say WordPress - nowadays uses a lot of Javascript but does not necessarily need a big front end framework. I am looking for a middle way between putting all scripts under each other in one file and using a big framework with way more than it should do.

Comment: ah ok now i got it. Why don't use angularJS? its really easy to handle and its not too big i think. But note that AngularJS 2 will be released soon

Comment: Use a bundler. Let's you put smaller modules together to construct your pages without touching angular/backbone/whatever. Smaller modules are put together into a single file to reduce load time.

Comment: Hi Daniel, what would you suggest as a bundler?

Comment: Were you able to find something @LilleHummer? It IS true, the internet will either point you to a framework or tell you that some code in a random js file will do

Comment: What I was looking for is how to structure and maintain Javascript for bigger websites - some sliders, carousels, lazy loading, other jQuery plugins. So not something big like Angular or anything for SPA's. It looks like using the module design pattern, reading some more on structuring Javascript - seperating DOM, events, etc - is most useful now. I think the best solution would be using Backbone.js in the end.

I didn't find the silver bullet yet and indeeed online articles mostly mention SPA's and big frameworks or some small code snippet.

Any suggestions for literature are very welcome. :)

Comment: If you have lots of single independent components, your current approach (with module patterns etc) should work fine. If your code becomes a mess because all the components conflict in their usage of global state, then you *want* a framework.

Comment: Hi Bergi, thanks a lot for your feedback, that was about what I figured in the past few months. For bigger applications I am thinking of picking VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question would now be: Use VueJS.